# Load more than 200 assets into a multi-asset WO?

Tags: maximo

Maximo 7.6.1.1 and Spatial 7.6.0.5:

I can load assets from the List View into a work order:

- Create (Spatial) `-->` Work Order with All Records

[image]

*Related info here: [Creating sets of work orders and service requests](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSG2D3_7.5.0/com.ibm.spl.doc/maps/t_create_set_wo_sr.html)*

---

Unfortunately, this action is limited to 200 records:

[image]

```
BMXAA2333E - Please narrow your results down to a maximum of 200 rows to perform this action.
```

---

Is there a way to load more than 200 assets at a time into a multi-asset WO?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Go To > System Configuration > Platform Configuration > System
>   Properties
>
> 2) In the System Properties app, filter for "maxselectrows"
>
> 3) Expand the "webclient.maxselectrows" property. Set the "Global
>   Value" to 3000 or whatever you prefer.
>
> 4) Hit Save.

Source: [Scroll arrows won't go past 200 items](http://ibm.com/support/pages/scroll-arrows-wont-go-past-200-items)

---

Alternatively, for the customization route, see:

```
maximouiweb.war.WEB-INF.classes.psdi.pluss.webclient.beans.plusspss.PlusSConfirmSelectionDialogBean
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition I had to increase "mxe.db.sqlserverPrefetchRows" as well.